# The Labels did not created dynamically after Event fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add 'i' days to date which is selected from textBox(StartDate_TB)

and I want to store them in sql server after Finish button clicked.....

```
<div class="box-content">
 <div id="Div1" class="wizard">
 <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span></li>
 <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span></li>
 <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span></li>
 <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span></li>
 <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span></li>
 </ul>
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-content">
<div class="step-pane active" id="Div2" runat="server">
    <div class="control-group ">
        <div class="controls">
            <h1>Create a new event<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" cssclass="control-label"></asp:textbox>
                starting on 
                <asp:textbox id="TextBox2" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2 input-xlarge datepicker"></asp:textbox>
                for
                <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span1" onselectedindexchanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" autopostback="true">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:dropdownlist>
                days. </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="step-pane" id="Div3" runat="server">
        <div class="control-group ">
            <h1>Matching making will be held on the following days:
                                           <br />
                <br />
            </h1>
            <div class="row-fluid" runat="server" id="Div4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="step-pane" id="Div5">

        <h1>Matchmaking starts at 
            <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
             </asp:dropdownlist>
            and ends at
            <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList3" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2">
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="6:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>

             </asp:dropdownlist>
            .<br /><br />
            Each slot is 
            <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList4" runat="server" autopostback="True" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2" onselectedindexchanged="SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:dropdownlist>
            minutes long. </h1>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-pane" id="Div6">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="control-group ">
            <h1>The following slots are available for Matchmaking.
                                        <br />
            </h1>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                Turn off any slots you wish to disable.
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <h1>
                        <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:label>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="task low" runat="server" id="Div7">
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-pane" id="Div8">
    <h1>Your event is ready!</h1>
</div>
```

Code Behind is..............

```
  protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i);//Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
    }
```

here I have taken the date from Calender, but I want to take the date from the TextBox, which have dropdown calender(by using the twitter bootstrap class, I got the calender in the textbox) and I want to add 'i' days to the selected date.......???

Comment: is `DateTimeValue.AddDays(i);` suitable fo you?

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);   var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i); is this correct

Comment: yes, just be sure your textbox have valid DateTime

Comment: but it doesn't work..... pls see code I updated as above mentioned....

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: No error.... but,The Event did not fired..............

Comment: changes made shouldn't alter conditions for event trigger.

Comment: now I set AutoPostback=True; then event fired, but Labels did not created dynamically..............

Comment: Then What can I do????

Comment: if markup you provided is complete you miss binding `SelectedIndexChanged` to whatever dropdown it should bind to. Also I cant find any `<div>` with Id == Labeldiv. If you declare these controls from codebehind - please post their entire declaration block

Comment: I edited... pls see once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is perfectly valid. Markup - is not.

It seems you obfuscated controls Ids or copied them from another source - any way, they are reset. After restoring them to proper values everything goes smoothly: event fires and labels are added dynamicaly.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div id="Div1" class="wizard">
                <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span></li>
                <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span></li>
                <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span></li>
                <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span></li>
                <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span></li>
                </ul>
  <div class="actions">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="step-content">
                <div class="step-pane active" id="Div2" runat="server">
                    <div class="control-group ">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <h1>Create a new event<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="control-label"></asp:TextBox>
                                starting on 
                <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate_TB" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2 input-xlarge datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                                for
                <asp:DropDownList ID="EventDuration_DDL" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                                days. </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="step-pane" id="Div3" runat="server">
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            <h1>Matching making will be held on the following days:
                                           <br />
                                <br />
                            </h1>
                            <div class="row-fluid" runat="server" id="Labeldiv">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="step-pane" id="Div5">

                        <h1>Matchmaking starts at 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2">
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
                            and ends at
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2">
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="6:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>
                            .<br />
                            <br />
                            Each slot is 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
                            minutes long. </h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="step-pane" id="Div6">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            <h1>The following slots are available for Matchmaking.
                                        <br />
                            </h1>
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                Turn off any slots you wish to disable.
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span6">
                                    <h1>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label_1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </h1>
                                    <div class="task low" runat="server" id="Div7">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="step-pane" id="Div8">
                    <h1>Your event is ready!</h1>
                </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok... now I want save values into sql server after only finish button click... how??? Our Button is not asp Button.... then how can we save...

Comment: can you change it to asp:button? you don't lose any flexibility of plain html button but get support of server event handling.

Comment: when I changed it to asp:Button, It did not go to next wizard.... I mentioned in the above Questionthat it has 5 steps.... next, next.... last one is finish.